# A variation on four-vertex theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, curvature, curves

Is it true that, if a closed, strictly convex curve has exactly four vertices (extrema of curvature), then any circle has at most four points of intersection with it?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I understand that the Moon's trajectory is strictly convex with respect to the Sun, yet it intersects the Earth's orbit about 26 times. I'm not sure what a "vertex" of a curve is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: a vertex of a smooth curve is an extremum point of the curvature. This question is related to the classical "four vertex theorem": every smooth closed convex curve has at least four vertices.

Comment: Thanks, @Ivan. That makes my Moon comment totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is true. More generally, if a smooth closed strictly convex curve intersects some circle in $2n$ points, then it has at least $2n$ vertices. This is stated in Blaschke's book "Kreis und Kugel" at the end of the Appendix on vertices of curves. For a proof, see

*Jackson, S. B.*, [**Vertices of plane curves**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1944-08190-1), Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 50, 564-578 (1944). [ZBL0060.34909](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0060.34909).